# Make left column in 2 column layout take up 100% height with Sticky Footer

Tags: css, html, layout, sticky-footer

I'm trying to figure out how to make the left column **take up 100% height in a 2 column layout with a sticky footer**.  The goal is for the sticky footer to **not get stuck until it runs into the content of the left column**.  I'm using the negative margin approach to the sticky footer.

Please look at the JSFiddle below.

http://jsfiddle.net/x11joex11/2Ljgze37/8/

**CSS:**

```
/* Set Defaults */
* {height:100%;margin:0;}
.wrapper{
    background-color:rgba(0,0,0,0.25);
    min-height: 100%;
    height: auto !important;
    height: 100%;
    margin:0 auto -50px;
}
.clear {clear:both}

/* Create Header */
.header{
    height:50px;
    background-color:rgba(0,255,0,0.5);
}

/* Content */
.content{
    height:100%;
    padding-right:100px;
}

/* Left Column */
.leftside{
    float:left;
    height:100%;
    width:100px;
    background-color:rgba(0,0,255,0.5);
}

/*Right Column*/
.rightside{
    float:right;
    margin: 0 -100px 0 0; width: 100%;
    background-color:rgba(255,0,255,0.5);
}
.push{
    height:50px;
}
.stickyfooter{
    height:50px;
    background-color:rgba(255,0,0,0.75);
}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="header">Header</div>
    <div class="content">
        <div class="leftside">
            Left Menu<br/><br/>
            Home<br/><br/>
            Page #1<br/><br/>
            Page #2<br/><br/>
            Page #3<br/><br/>
        </div>
        <div class="rightside">
            Right Content (lorem ipsum forgot the rest)
            (lorem ipsum forgot the rest)(lorem ipsum forgot the rest)
            (lorem ipsum forgot the rest)(lorem ipsum forgot the rest)
            (lorem ipsum forgot the rest)(lorem ipsum forgot the rest)
        </div>
        <div class="clear"></div>
        <div class="push"></div>
    </div>   
</div>
<div class="stickyfooter">Footer</div>
```

Comment: Can you please elaborate on **not get stuck until it runs into the content of the left column.** ? I can't help until I get what you mean.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was playing around with your Fiddle, and the first thing that comes to mind is we need to make an absolutely positioned background for your side nav.

You can add this outside your wrapper:

```
<div class="left-bg"></div>
```

and this css:

```
.left-bg {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    background-color:rgba(0,0,255,0.5);
    width:100px;
    z-index: -1;
}
```

Height doesn't work the same with Floats, you can also Absolutely position your content wrapper and the side nav and it should have 100% height that way, then use min-height to cause your footer to stop and not cover the content in your nav.

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/3t5r2qg3/

---

As Joseph said in the comments, it is better in this scenario to use 'position: fixed;' compared to 'position: absolute;'

Comment: Thank you so much, exactly what I was looking for! Genius solution using absolute position to repeat the pattern on the left with z-index: -1 so header, footer still above while retaining height 100%

Comment: I want to note, that it's better to change the position to Fixed, instead of absolute.  The reason for this is it adapts to the browser height not just what you see visually on the screen.  (refer to this, http://css-tricks.com/absolute-relative-fixed-positioining-how-do-they-differ/), if you add a lot of content in the left menu then shrink the browser window and scroll down you'll see the background div disapear if it's not 'fixed' position.

Answer (score 0):

Played around and updated your fiddle to your spec:

http://jsfiddle.net/YoshiMaster/2Ljgze37/18/

Honestly can't remember all the steps I took, but the main one was to set the .content style to

```
display: table;
```

and its children to

```
display: table-cell;
```

then I switched some divs around and added another div to wrap the content.